# Please suggest me Details of HEX and NDEF format RFID tags

Tags: android

will you please tell me exact difference between HEX and NDEF format as I am getting confused by RFID tags
I searched a lot. sorry for inconvenience I am asking again and again about RFId
It will be great helpfull if you guyz suggest me any reader and RFId chips to buy so that i can check ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RFID tag can typically hold a certain number of bytes, often organized into blocks of 4 or 8 bytes each. The layout and the commands to access this information differs from chip to chip. I guess this is what you mean by HEX format.

NDEF is a higher level specifiaction to access information on chips in a more standardized way by reading and writing NDEF messages. Some driver software will map the NDEF message into the bytes of the chip.